# Why does the 'git status' command ask to commit changes made by another developer?

Tags: git, github, gitlab, repository, bitbucket

I am new to Git. I forked a Git repository and cloned it. I have created a new file in the local directory and executed the below commands:

```
git add filename
git commit -m "message"
```

And before I do a Git push I have executed "git status" to verify and then it shows the below message:

```
on branch master
your branch and origin/master is diverged and have 1 and 2 different commits each
All conflicts fixed but you are still merging

changes to be committed
new file : xxxxxxx

pulling without specifying how to reconcile divergent branches is discouraged.
error: you have not concluded your merge (MERGE_HEAD EXISTS)
hint: Please, commit your changes before merging.
exiting because of unfinished merge
```

Why do I need to commit which is not changed by mine? And when I enter *"git push"* for my created file, it says

```
updates were rejected because the tip of your branch is behind its remote counterpart.
Integrate the remote changes/
```

What is the reason behind this unknown commit? Should I commit those and then use "git push" for my changes to push?

Comment: I think you should do a "git pull --rebase" to update your local branch with changes from remote, and then you will be able to push the changes.

Comment: You started a `git merge` (perhaps via `git pull`) and have not finished it. You may have started the merge days or weeks ago, but you still haven't finished it. You must finish it (or terminate it with `git merge --abort`, but if you choose to do that, be careful because things you have done since then may be lost).

Comment: Note, too, that `git merge` means *combine work*, so this may well want you to commit someone else's work as part of the combining. That's quite normal: if you eliminate their work, you're telling Git that the *correct* way to combine your work with their work is to *discard* their work, so be sure that you really mean that.